# Error with instance variable in Index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So in my `tutors_controller.rb` this is my index action

```
  def index
    @tutor = Tutor.all
    @tutor = @tutor.fees_search(params[:fees_search]) if params[:fees_search].present?
  end
```

and in my `index.html.erb` this is the view

```
<div class='container'>
  <%= form_tag(tutors_path, method: :get) do %>
    <%= label_tag 'fees_search', 'Max Fees' %>
    <%= select_tag 'fees_search', options_for_select((10..50).step(10)) %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
  <% end %>
  <% @tutor.each do |tutor| %>
    <% unless tutor.admin? %>
      <div class='row' id='tutor-listing'>
        <div class='col-xs-4'>
          <%= image_tag(tutor.profile.avatar.url, :class => "img-rounded" ) if tutor.profile.avatar? %>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-8'>
          <h3><%= link_to tutor.full_name, tutor_path(tutor) %></h3>
          <% unless tutor.subjects.nil? %>
            <% tutor.subjects.each do |subs| %>
                <span class='badge'id='tutor-listing-badge'>
                  <%= link_to subs.name, subject_path(subs) %>
                </span>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
          <% unless current_tutor %>
            <%= button_to "Shortlist Tutor", add_to_cart_path(tutor.id), :method => :post %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div> 
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

So i understand that when the index view first renders, `@tutor` would simply be `Tutor.all` so it renders each individual tutor perfectly.

After trying to filter it though, i start receiving errors. The exact error is `NoMethodError in Tutors#index`and the highlighted line is `<% unless tutor.admin? %>`

[image]

`profile.rb` model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tutor
  scope :fees_to, -> (fees_to) { where("fees_to <= ?", "#{fees_to}") }
end
```

`tutor.rb` model

```
class Tutor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  def self.fees_search(n)
    @profile = Profile.fees_to(n)
    if @profile.empty?
      return Tutor.none
    else
      @profile.each do |y|
        y.tutor
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I get that now my `@tutor` instance variable has obviously changed. But how do i go about resolving this problem? Should i be rendering a partial instead? Obviously my index action in my controller could be "better" also but i'm quite confused now as to what i should be doing.

Would appreciate any advice! Thank you!

Comment: What is the exact error? Please post it in the question.

Comment: @Pavan i've edited it to show the exact error i am currently receiving

Comment: Do you have any method/attribute called `admin` in `tutor` model?

Comment: @Pavan i have an admin column in my Tutor's schema and its a boolean type. My index view works perfectly fine prior to processing to filter. It renders all Tutors that are admin => false.

Comment: Your error is still uncomplete. It should be saying undefined method. Plase post it.

Comment: @Pavan i have attached a photo of the error i am receiving instead. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: It says undefined method for Profile not Tutor. So there is nothing wrong with Tutor model. Something is messing with the Profile model. Can you post your Profile model?

Comment: @Pavan i have added profile model and also tutor model which defines the method fees_search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@profile.each do |y|
  y.tutor
end
```

Seems to be a problem. All the other outcomes are a `Tutor.something` scope, whereas this will return the last tutor only. Change `each` to `map` to get an array of `Tutors` instead.

Comment: works like a charm! thank you so much! i shall go read up on `.map` method. cheers